# PayPal Website Payments Pro API Not Receiving All Data

Tags: api, paypal, nvp, website-payment-pro

I'm using the PayPal WPP API to try to process payments. When I complete a payment, not all of the data I have mapped is displayed (or accurate) in the transaction details. For instance, Order Description, Billing Address, Card Security Code are all either blank or displaying what I assume is default information. I receive no error back from the API, and everything else is mapped correctly.

Here's the postdata (made to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp via cURL but I have users reporting this on the live endpoint as well)

`METHOD=DoDirectPayment&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=IP-REMOVED&VERSION=95.0&BUTTONSOURCE=Formstack_Cart_WPP_US&USER=SANDBOX-CREDENTIALS-REMOVED&PWD=SANDBOX-CREDENTIALS-REMOVED&SIGNATURE=SANDBOX-CREDENTIALS-REMOVED&AMT=3&HANDLINGAMT=&SHIPPINGAMT=&TAXAMT=&DESC=test+test+test&INVNUM=&CURRENCYCODE=&ACCT=4539644852839411&CVV2=323&EXPDATE=012016&EMAIL=test%40test.test&SHIPTOPHONENUM=&FIRSTNAME=test2&LASTNAME=test&STREET=test&STREET2=&CITY=test&STATE=AL&ZIP=12345&COUNTRYCODE=US&L_AMT0=3.00&L_QTY0=1&L_NAME0=Paypal+Pro&ITEMAMT=3`

I have tried removing the NVP for empty values, and I can find no other results about this issue. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the API response you are getting back so that I can look up the transaction on my end to see what may be happening?

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad 

```[TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-21T13:02:28Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => aadac76db6347
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 56.0
    [BUILD] => 5908853
    [AMT] => 5.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => X
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 1PM18329A75739915```

I realize that the version number is way behind the current version, but I've even set the version to 95 and still encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the API request you provided (with my own credentials) and the item details appeared properly. I added another line item and submitted it again. Here is the request and a screen shot:

```
METHOD=DoDirectPayment&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=216.1.1.1&VERSION=95.0&BUTTONSOURCE=Formstack_Cart_WPP_US&USER=x&PWD=x&SIGNATURE=x&AMT=6&HANDLINGAMT=&SHIPPINGAMT=&TAXAMT=&DESC=test+test+test&INVNUM=&CURRENCYCODE=&ACCT=4539644852839411&CVV2=323&EXPDATE=012016&EMAIL=test%40test.test&SHIPTOPHONENUM=&FIRSTNAME=test2&LASTNAME=test&STREET=test&STREET2=&CITY=test&STATE=AL&ZIP=12345&COUNTRYCODE=US&L_AMT0=3.00&L_QTY0=1&L_NAME0=Paypal+Pro&L_AMT1=3.00&L_QTY1=1&L_NAME1=Paypal+Pro+2&ITEMAMT=6
```

[image]

If you have a transaction ID I can look it up and see if something was sent over incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I may not have been clearer before. The issue is not that the item information isn't being sent. It's the transaction information (and billing address). Looking at your screenshot, you're getting the same issue I am. The Order Description is Shopping Cart even though it should be Test Test Test and the Address is blank even though data is being sent.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I understand now. I tried passing L_DESC0 and L_DESC1 but nothing changed. I'll submit a ticket to our Sandbox engineering team to get that fixed - sorry!
The billing address won't appear in PayPal unfortunately. If you're using a new Payments Pro account (with Payflow Pro) you can use the Payflow API calls and the Payflow reports including the billing address.

Comment: Do you have any update on this, or somewhere I can check on this myself?

Comment: You can create a ticket on the MTS site (PayPal.com/mts), send me the ticket number, and I'll keep you updated as it goes.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Experiencing the same thing, though the documentation I have refers to `ORDERDESC=xxx` rather than `DESC=xxx`.